# Managed Bean method authorization using custom java annotations in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, annotations

I would like to create a custom annotation to decorate methods which would restrict access to method calls.

My annotation is defined below:

```
@Inherited
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Restrict {
   public enum RoleType {All, ROLE_A, ROLE_B, ROLE_C, ROLE_D}
   String roleLevel();
   RoleType roleType();
}
```

Then using the annotation like the following.  The annotation receives two parameters, one being the required minimum roleType, the other the required minimum role level.

```
@Restrict(roleType = RoleType.ALL, roleLevel="user")
String deleteSomething() {
  // delete intended whatever
  return success;
}
```

My intent is, when any call to a Managed Bean method that is decorated with this annotation, as in the method described above "deleteSomething()", occurs, this call would be intercepted and the parameters set on the method compared to the logged in users appropriate session values.  If the logged in users session role values are high enough, the Managed Bean's method will be allowed to be invoked, otherwise the user is either redirected or an appropriate message is displayed.

My question is this, is there a way I can "hook" into what methods are bing called to then, through reflection, see if there is a @Restrict annotation on the method and then process said annotation.  I've tried doing this in a PhaseListener class, but I'm not sure how to find out what Managed Bean is being called to perform refection on.  I've read about a custome ElResolver, but I'm not sure if this is anything that will help me.  I've also tried to find a way to simply create a listener that somehow knows when a method that is annotated with @Restrict has been invoked.

```
Environment Specifics:

Tomcat 6.0.35 (considering upgrading to Tomcat 7.0.27)
JSF version 2.1.7
RichFaces 4.1.0
```

I'm just looking for some guidance and some options available to me.  Thank you to anyone who can help me with this!

Comment: By coincidence, someone else asked the same question this week and the solution was to use a custom `ActionListener` implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660273/custom-annotation-jsf

Comment: @BalusC Thanks BalusC for your time and quick response.  Correct me if I am wrong, but the solution in your link using an ActionListener  only handles the expressions in the "action" attribute?  How would I handle ajax calls.  Also, I am not using JaaS.  We simply set an object on the session for the user.  That object contains permission information and we use a filter for authentication.  Do I need to implement something like JaaS to make what I want work? My knowledge of these technologies is limited, so any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's also invoked on ajax calls. Just check if the to-be-invoked action is an action or an action listener. JaaS is not required. The point is that you can use an `ActionListener` to hook on this.

Comment: @BalusC Excellent.  I'll give this approach a try.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!  How do I award points and to whom should I award them?  To you for the direction or do I up-vote the question in the link you proided (as there is no answer to up-vote).

Comment: Okay, I'll repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing a custom [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ActionListener.html) which is been registered as a global `<action-listener>` in the `faces-config.xml`.

By coincidence, someone else asked and answered the same question this week: [Custom Annotation JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660273/custom-annotation-jsf). Note that JAAS is not required for the particular purpose, just grab the `User` from the session by `FacesContext` the usual way.