# JSF CDI @Named + isAnnotationPresent + @CustomSecurityAnnotation

Tags: jsf, reflection, cdi, omnifaces

I'm using a custom annotation security [as described in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660273/custom-annotation-jsf). I'm upgrading my jsf managed beans from @ManagedBean to @Named (CDI). Since the CDI does not support the scope @ViewScoped, i'm using org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped. However, in this case, this check fails `if method.isAnnotationPresent(Permissao.class){}`. How should I adapt my security check to use with CDI + ViewScoped from Omnifaces?

**Edit**

Using @ManagedBean/ViewScoped(jsf) instead of @Named/ViewScoped(cdi + omnifaces) works.
The problem occurs in this line `if (metodo.isAnnotationPresent(Permissao.class)) {}`

```
public void verificaPermissaoAcesso(ActionEvent event) {

    final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    UIComponent source = event.getComponent();
    ActionSource2 actionSource = (ActionSource2) source;
    MethodExpression methodExpression = actionSource.getActionExpression();
    String expressao = methodExpression.getExpressionString();  // #{nomeManagedBean.nomeMetodo(param)} 

    String nomeManagedBean = expressao.substring(0, expressao.indexOf('.')).substring(2);
    String nomeMetodoComParenteses = expressao.substring(expressao.indexOf('.') + 1);        
    String nomeMetodo = nomeMetodoComParenteses.substring(0, nomeMetodoComParenteses.indexOf("("));

    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory factory = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    ValueExpression ve = factory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{" + nomeManagedBean + '}', Object.class);
    //Object jsfManagedBean = ve.getValue(elContext);

    Context ctx = bm.getContext(org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped.class);
    Bean bean = bm.resolve(bm.getBeans(nomeManagedBean));
    Object jsfManagedBeanProxy = ctx.get(bean);

    List<Method> listaMetodos = Arrays.asList(jsfManagedBeanProxy.getClass().getMethods());

    for (Method metodo : listaMetodos) {
        if (nomeMetodo.equals(metodo.getName())) {
            if (metodo.isAnnotationPresent(Permissao.class)) {
                Permissao anotacaoSeguranca = metodo.getAnnotation(Permissao.class);
                SegurancaUtil.verificar(anotacaoSeguranca.acoes());
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

My annotation class

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Permissao {
    String[] acoes();
}
```

My annotated method in jsf managed bean

```
@Permissao(acoes={"permission1", "permission2"})
public void myMethod(long id) {}
```

**Edit 2 - Solution by @meriton**

```
Context ctx = bm.getContext(org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped.class);
Bean bean = bm.resolve(bm.getBeans(nomeManagedBean));
Object jsfManagedBeanProxy = ctx.get(bean);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDI doesn't inject a naked CDI bean as a dependency, but a proxy that redirects to the contextual object of the active scope. This proxy class does not have your annotation.

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-10 for how to unwrap the proxy.

Comment: Thanks @meriton. Updated the main post with the changes.